# How to login to PostgreSQL with different username than "postgres" and how to encrypt specific columns?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, encryption

I am absolutely new to PostgreSQL. I have the following doubts:

1. I am able to login to postgresql using

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql postgres
   ```

   I have created a `test_db` database and inside it a table called `test_tbl`. I have also created a user `test` and given it the below privileges:

   ```
   GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE test_db TO test;
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON test_tbl TO test;
   ```

   How do I login to the `test_db` database as `test` user? I am only able to login as `postgres`. If I try login as `test` I get the below error-

```
        ubuntu@ip-10-81-1-44:~$ psql -U test -d test_db
        psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test"
```

2. How can I encrypt a specific column in table `test_tbl`, just for user `test` and no other user?

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to `sudo` change your user, you can specify that on connect using the `-U` flag, like so:

`psql -U test -d test_db`

this will try to connect you to the database `test_db` as user `test` and if a password is required you will be prompted, other flags such as host, port etc are listed here

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: I get the below error when I run psql -U test -d test_db -" psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "test"

Answer (score 1):

1. You will have to create an entry in `pg_hba.conf` that allows the user into the database. Don't forget to reload PostgreSQL.

   Read [the documentation about client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) for more.
2. To encrypt a column, you need application code that does the encryption and decryption.

   Perhaps you can get what you want with column privileges:

   ```
   GRANT SELECT ON test_tbl TO test;
   GRANT SELECT (col1, col2, ...) ON test_tbl TO PUBLIC;
   ```

   Here you list all columns except the one you want to hide.
   Then only user `test` can `SELECT` that column.

   An alternative is to restrict `SELECT` to `test` only and provide to the others a view that shows everything except the hidden columns.